# Linking two arrays in Actionscript 3

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

Very new to actionscript,

Im trying to link two arrays. Basically I have a word array of 8 words and I have a movie clip array of 8 movieclips. My aim is to link the two arrays so that the user must click the right movie clip that matches the word that was displayed on screen.

All help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to have one array of objects, each with two fields?

Comment: Ya it probably would, how do you write that code? I've just began to teach myself so I don't know the correct terminology or have a lot of knowledge

Comment: FYI, you should post your second question as a separate question instead of editing this one to ask two things.  See also [these](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10243/asking-a-follow-up-question) [two](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266767/what-is-the-the-best-way-to-ask-follow-up-questions) Meta questions on the topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var listAry:Array = [];
var orangeJuice:Object = new Object();
orangeJuice.name= "Orange Juice";
orangeJuice.matchingImage=oj;
listAry[0]=orangeJuice;
////etc etc
```

There you go buddy. Hope that helps if you have any questions just ask.

Comment: do I keep the vars I have above aswell, therefore - randomlistword, matchingimages & randomnumber? Or just get rid of randomlistword?

Comment: basically if you define the properties of each object in your array with the name and the matchingImage you don't need any of the other variables (except your randomNumber of course)

Comment: ok thanks, I implemented this into my code and now when it displays listAry on page, instead of displaying just the randomly generated name it displays [object Object], how can I just make it show my word?

Comment: replace randomword.text = randomlistword[randomnumber]; with randomword.text = listAry[randomnumber].name; access any property you want like so

Comment: Your a star, everything is working perfectly now! Accepted your answer

Comment: glad I could be of service. Good luck with your project

Comment: One more quick question @DrakeSwartzy and I will leave you be haha, how do I call a function if the image clicked is equal to its matching word?

Comment: @user3594463 you would use something along the lines of: if(imageClicked==correctItem.image){ then....} ... hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is with a [Dictionary](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html).

```
var foodionary:Dictionary = new Dictionary();

foodionary["Orange Juice"] = oj;
foodionary["Sandwich"] = sand;
//etc...

for(var key:String in foodionary) {
    trace(key + " matches with " + foodionary[key].id); //assuming your images have ids
}
```

For random access, though, you'll still need an array (or a [Vector](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Vector.html)):

```
function displayword(){

    randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * randomlistword.length);
    trace("random number = " + randomnumber);

    var chosenword = randomlistword[randomnumber];
    randomword.text = chosenword
    randomword.img = foodionary[chosenword];
    randomlistword.splice(randomnumber, 1);
    trace("randomlistword array: " + randomlistword);

}//close displayword function
```